# How can I link my admob ad units to my app before uploading to app store?

Tags: ios, admob, app-store, app-store-connect

I have been working on an app to submit to the apple app store.  It is almost finished, however, I am experiencing a bit of confusion on integrating admob in my final submission.  I have tested the app and confirmed that the admob service work with the admob test codes.  However, I see in admob that I need to link my ad units to an app in the app store already in the store order for it to work.  But, I need the ads need to be working when I submit my app for review in order for apple to accept the app and allow it onto the app store.  So how should I proceed?